# Dynamic or conditional Join

Tags: sql, join, plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to dynamically join tables using SQL (or PL/SQL)?

I have a **TableA** with multiple columns. Each column below has its own separate table, except id.

```
|  id | AA | BB | CC | DD | EE |
|-----|----|----|----|----|----|
| 123 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| 456 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
| 789 |  1 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
.......
```

Based on the value of the columns I need to join tables.

- For **id = 123** I would like to join the **CC**, **DD**, **EE** tables.
- For **id = 456** I would like to join the **AA**, **BB**, **DD**, **EE** tables.
- For **id = 789** I would like to join the **AA**, **CC** tables.
- And so on.
- And finally union the result in one table.
- Also, tables **AA**, **BB**, **CC**, **DD**, **EE** have the same set of columns.

Example data:

Table **AA**

```
|  id | Value |
|-----|-------|
| 456 |   bbb |
| 789 |   ccc |
```

Table **BB**

```
|  id | Value |
|-----|-------|
| 789 |   ccc |
| 456 |   bbb |
```

Table **CC**

```
|  id | Value |
|-----|-------|
| 123 |   aaa |
| 789 |   ccc |
```

Table **DD**

```
|  id | Value |
|-----|-------|
| 123 |   aaa |
```

Table **EE**

```
|  id | Value |
|-----|-------|
| 123 |   aaa |
```

**Expected Output**

```
|  id | Value |
|-----|-------|
| 123 |   abc |
| 789 |   ccc |
```

**id 456** would not be part of final result as it would be filtered out when joining.

Is it possible to do so in SQL or PL/SQL (plain SQL preferred). Also: I want to do an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: You should edit your query with sample data *and* desired results.

Comment: What a reason you put a period after the value? And could you post DDL for the tables?

Comment: That was the typo. Updated the question

Comment: Supposed, it were possible to `JOIN` dynamically (which it is not): Given the tables **AA** through **EE** do -as per your description- "have same set of columns" AND you want to "finally union the result in one big tab" - what would the individual joins look like? In order to `UNION` them, you can't select all columns of all tables each time, as per your examples, the number of tables (and thus columns) could differ - whilst all `SELECT`s in a `UNION` must have the same number of columns.  -- Structure of the tables, sample data and expected output might help to find a solution...

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data *and* desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: A table with multiple columns and each column has its own table. This is poor table design and it will lead to endless trouble. Suggest you get some assistance rerdesigning the tables for 3rd normal form.

Comment: Don't know the problem domain. Find it hard to imagine a valid use case for the suggested table design with no further information. So some background information might make it easier to follow your reasoning... - Apart from that: You store data in five auxiliary tables - and want just a single **value** in the output?

Comment: I guess, **123 abc** for expected output is a typo, as you stored always **aaa** for **123**.

Comment: Yes, want single table output. Anyways, seems like it may be hard to do with sql only. I will try it with some programming language

Comment: I did understand (right from the beginning), you want a single output table. I'm wondering about the two column format (with just a single (copy? of the) value of that output table. Which is after spreading the value(s) over so many tables earlier on... No clue either, how the "finally union the result in one table" fits into this picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asked for `JOIN` of **TableA** and tables **AA** through **EE** (and all of this `UNION`ed up) should probably look similar to the output of

```
WITH
TableAUnpivot AS (
  SELECT
    id
    , tableName
  --  , value
  FROM
    TableA UNPIVOT EXCLUDE NULLS
      (VALUE FOR(tableName) IN ( "AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE")
      )
),
DataTablesCombined AS (
  SELECT 'AA' tableName, id, value FROM AA UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BB', id, value FROM BB UNION ALL
  SELECT 'CC', id, value FROM CC UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DD', id, value FROM DD UNION ALL
  SELECT 'EE', id, value FROM EE
),
ReadyForJoin AS (
  SELECT
    id
    , tableName
    , value
  FROM TableAUnpivot
  JOIN DataTablesCombined
    USING (tableName, id)
),
LookLikeAJoin AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM ReadyForJoin
  PIVOT (MIN(value) FOR tableName
         IN ('AA' AS AA, 'BB' AS BB, 'CC' AS CC, 'DD' AS DD, 'EE' AS EE))
)
SELECT
  * FROM LookLikeAJoin ORDER BY id
;
```

which for the sample data is

```
|  ID |     AA |     BB |     CC |     DD |     EE |
|-----|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| 123 | (null) | (null) |    aaa |    aaa |    aaa |
| 456 |    bbb |    bbb | (null) | (null) | (null) |
| 789 |    ccc | (null) |    ccc | (null) | (null) |
```

where a cell is different from **NULL**, iff:

- it has been set **1** in **TableA**, and
- been assigned a value in the respective table **AA** through **EE**.

**NB:** For this to work at all, all **0**s in **TableA** had to be **NULL**ified.

Provided, this goes into the right direction: How to continue from here?

The most straightforward way appears to be to replace the final `SELECT` by

```
SELECT
  id, COALESCE(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) value FROM LookLikeAJoin WHERE id != 456 ORDER BY id
;
```

(Given, the **abc** for **123** is a typo...)

See the above in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b0cc1/2).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Thankyou so much !! You are spot on with the requirement and it seems like this will work fine. I will further test this and let you know if anything else is need . Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

You join *all* the tables and pull out the columns you need.  Note that a SQL query defines a set of columns that are fixed for all rows.  So, it doesn't really make sense to "conditionally" join in a table.  Where are you going to use the columns?

For your purpose you want `left join`:

```
select <columns that you want>
from table t left join
     students s
     on . . . left join
     classes c
     on . . . left join
     . . .
```

EDIT:

Your revised question is *very* different and should have been another question.  But, I think this does what you want:

```
select
from a join
     (select 1 as aa, 0 as bb, 0 as cc, 0 as dd, 0 as ee, id, value from aa union all
      select 0 as aa, 1 as bb, 0 as cc, 0 as dd, 0 as ee, id, value from bb union all
      select 0 as aa, 0 as bb, 1 as cc, 0 as dd, 0 as ee, id, value from cc union all
      select 0 as aa, 0 as bb, 0 as cc, 1 as dd, 0 as ee, id, value from dd union all
      select 0 as aa, 0 as bb, 0 as cc, 0 as dd, 1 as ee, id, value from ee 
     ) o
     on a.id = o.id and
        a.aa = o.aa and a.bb = o.bb and a.cc = o.cc and a.dd = o.dd and a.ee = o.ee;
```

Comment: Left join will not work. I have updated the question to be more clear

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this. However, the table with 1 and 0 is small subset of actual table. The actual table will contain many more rows and combinations

Comment: @ZAKB . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a different question.